# How to specify the timestamp format when creating a table using a hdfs directory

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, cloudera, impala

I have the following csv file located at the `path/to/file` in my hdfs store.

```
1842,10/1/2017 0:02
7424,10/1/2017 4:06
```

I'm trying to create a table using the below command:

```
create external table t
(
number          string,
reported_time  timestamp
)
ROW FORMAT delimited fields terminated BY ',' 
LOCATION 'path/to/file';
```

I can see in the impala query editor that the `reported_time` column in the table `t` is always null. I guess this is due the fact that my timestamp wasn't in an accepted timestamp format.

**Question:**

How can I specify that the timestamp column should be of the `dd/mm/yyyy hh:min` format so that it correctly parses the timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the timestamp(as per my exp*) but you can create the table with string data type and then you can convert string to timestamp as below:

```
select number,
       reported_time,
       from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(reported_time),'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm') as reported_time
from t;
```